# Check duplicate document in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, library, file, content, duplicate

We are building a SharePoint site for my business team. One important functionality is "Upload" using which they can upload documents/ files/ videos to the library.

Recently, I saw the same video file uploaded to the library by three users but with different file names. I somehow managed to catch this (based on duration) and manually removed the duplicates.

I wanted to check if there is an automated option/ tools compatible with SharePoint to check if there are duplicate files.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the duplicate documents by enabling the `Show View Duplicates link` in **`the search results web part`** settings.

[image]

**For more details, please  check**

- [Near-duplicate items aren't listed in SharePoint Online or SharePoint Server 2013 on-premises search results](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/near-duplicate-items-aren-t-listed-in-sharepoint-online-or-sharepoint-server-2013-on-premises-search-results-c38d6c67-8124-46a3-b2ba-e30129a17bbf)
- [Finding Duplicate Files in SharePoint](https://www.aquaforest.com/wp/index.php/finding-duplicate-files-in-sharepoint/)